# Incomplete Implementation and Method Definition ".." not found

Tags: xcode, implementation

I'm a beginner in Xcode and I have a problem. 
When I started my App in the iOS Simulator the App started an then failed. 
It tell me that I've an Incomplete Implementation. It says Method Definiton for "page" not found.

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>




@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@property(nonatomic, retain) MKMapView *mapView;

-(IBAction)page:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MapKit/MapKit.h"



  @interface ViewController : UIViewController {



 IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
     IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *maptype;

}


- (IBAction)locate:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)page:(id)sender;

@end
```

---

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary     *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"      bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Can someone help ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: where did you define the body of your method `-(IBAction)page:(id)sender;` you have that same method declared in your `AppDelegate.h` and `ViewController.h`. You should write the method body i.e, what the method should do when it is called, in your `ViewController.m` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check whether you have missed to define your method  in your `ViewController.m file`.

```
-(IBAction)page:(id)sender  
{   
// your code here  
}
```